# cant get List[String] from Future[List[String]] scala

Tags: spray, reactivemongo, spray-json

i tried

```
complete(db[BSONCollection("user").find(BSONDocument()).cursor[UserObject].collect[List]().toJson)
```

i tried that but i doesn't work
it gives me error

```
    Main.scala:101: Cannot find JsonWriter or     JsonFormat type class for scala.concurrent.Future[Option[UserObject]]
[error]                   complete(Themodel.get().toJson )
```

i tried

```
complete(collection.find(emptyQuery).cursor[BSONDocument].collect[List]()   map{ t => OK -> t})
```

but it gives me an error

```
found   : scala.concurrent.Future[(akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes.Success, Option[UserObject])]
[error]  required: spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable
[error]                   complete(Themodel.get() map{
[error]                                           ^
```

Answer (score 0):

well i found onComplete directive on sprayJson
http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/future-directives/onComplete/
hope to help any one who was on trouble like me

Answer (score 0):

I do not analyze you code. just title (List[String] from Future[List[String]]
). Your code probable is not for the production.

```
 val futureList: Future[List[String]] = Future(List("v","d","f"))

 val someOperationOnFuture: Future[List[String]] = futureList.map(_.map(_.toUpperCase()))
```

to get result you can use:

```
val res: List[String] = Await.result(futureList, 40.seconds)
```

but it do NOT the best way it is just example.

Read some information [Scala Future](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)

If you use [spray-json](https://github.com/spray/spray-json) It will help. I think